# Reusable cell old image showing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing a problem when scrolling from top to bottom of my `tableview`. The reusable cell shows old image until new image download is completed.

It should show my default image placeholder until new image is downloaded and when download is finished then change the imageView from image placeholder to current downloaded image. What should I do?

**Update**

TableViewcontroller :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemTableViewCell") as! ItemTableViewCell
        let itemInfo = itemInfos[indexPath.row]


        var image1 : UIImage?
        var image2 : UIImage?

        if let imgUrl1 = itemInfo.imageUrl  {

             image1 = ItemListViewController.imageCache.object(forKey: imgUrl1 as AnyObject) as? UIImage


        }

      if let imgUrl2 = itemInfo.cookerProfilePicUrl{
         image2 = ItemListViewController.imageCache.object(forKey: imgUrl2 as AnyObject) as? UIImage
        }

        cell.configureCell(iteminfo: itemInfo, img1 : image1 ,img2 : image2)

        return  cell
    }
```

Xib:

```
 func configureCell(iteminfo:ItemInfo , img1 : UIImage? , img2 : UIImage? ){

        if img1 != nil {
            imageViewItemPic.image = img1
        }
        else{
            print("hi1")
            imageViewItemPic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.imageUrl!)
        }


        if img2 != nil {
            imageViewCookerProfilePic.image = img2

        }
        else{
            imageViewCookerProfilePic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.cookerProfilePicUrl!)
        }

        labelItemHeading.text = iteminfo.heading
        labelItemDescription.text = iteminfo.description


    }
```

**update :**

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.imageViewItemPic.image = UIImage(named: "resto-placeholder.png")

    }
```

**Update :**

```
extension UIImageView {

    func setImageFromURL(url: String) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {

            let data = NSData.init(contentsOf: NSURL.init(string: url) as! URL)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let image = UIImage.init(data: data as! Data)

                ItemListViewController.imageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: url as AnyObject)

                self.image = image


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Rajat please check update section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is a reusable cell, it indeed "reuses" the cell with the old image. Then you need to update it every time the cell is shown in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        cell.image=placeholder_image
        //then download image
}
```

Comment: is it best practice ?

Comment: In your case, you can put this line in your configureCell method since you call it from cellForRowAt. But be sure to start with cell.image=placeholder_image so every new cell is initiated with placeholder, then download image. Then, if the download fails, the placeholder stays.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your default image in `ItemTableViewCell` when the cell is initialized

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.image= defaultImage
}
```

**Edit**

```
func configureCell(iteminfo:ItemInfo , img1 : UIImage? , img2 : UIImage? ){

        if img1 != nil {
            imageViewItemPic.image = img1
        }
        else{
            print("hi1")
           imageViewItemPic.image = UIImage(named: "resto-placeholder.png")

            imageViewItemPic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.imageUrl!)
        }


        if img2 != nil {
            imageViewCookerProfilePic.image = img2

        }
        else{
           imageViewItemPic.image = UIImage(named: "resto-placeholder.png")
            imageViewCookerProfilePic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.cookerProfilePicUrl!)
        }

        labelItemHeading.text = iteminfo.heading
        labelItemDescription.text = iteminfo.description


    }
```

Comment: please check my update section. is it correct way i done that ?

Comment: Yes its correct, what is this method `setImageFromURL` is it from any library ?

Comment: please check my update section . that is UIImage extension throwing a method

Comment: Edited my answer check this

Comment: check my answer,  i had to implement the default image as soon as receiving the data in the uitableviewcell..

Answer (score 1):

You must place an image for every `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, mean in your code you need to write `else` condition for image operation and in that you need to place an placeholder image. Because tableview cells are reused when you scroll up and down, so that if you won't place any new content it will keeps the old content, that's why it shows old/duplicate content.

Comment: If itemInfo contains the remote urls that needs to be download from server then,

Comment: if img1 != nil {
            imageViewItemPic.image = img1
        }
        else{
            print("hi1")
            imageViewItemPic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.imageUrl!)
        }

Comment: if img1 != nil {
            imageViewItemPic.image = img1
        }
        else{
            print("hi1")
            imageViewItemPic.image = UIImage(name:"placeholder")// When image download done, it will automatically updates the image by next statement that ypu written
            imageViewItemPic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.imageUrl!)
        }

Comment: post code in your answer and not in comment @NarendraKumarR

Answer (score 0):

just as i had the same problem; before reading this. i tried different ways such as the init and awakefromnib. the way to do it is just as soon as you receive the data before calling the func to update the whole UI.

Also, note im using a `var restData` and the `didSet` (this why it updates as soon as receiving the data from the viewcontroller, im not calling the func. if it was a func to call from the viewcontroller you would just put the placeholder image initially at the beginning of the func before downloading the new image and call it from the viewcontroller such as `cell.updateUI(data: data)`

Hope you guys find this useful. for me, im getting correct images without showing the preview image on the cell reuse :)

// tableview controller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell : RestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RestCell

    //configure the cell to item
   cell.restData = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

// UITableviewCell

```
 class RestCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var img : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var lbl : UILabel!

    // get data and update.
    var restData: RestsModel!  {
        didSet {
            // default img early placeholder set. Eliminates showing old pic in cell reuse
            self.img.image = UIImage(named: "60x60placeholder.png")
            // Update all values func
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Default image placeholder
       //self.img.image = UIImage(named: "60x60placeholder.png")

    }
    // required init.
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        // Color of selected.
        let myCustomSelectionColorView = UIView()
        myCustomSelectionColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 234.0/255.0, green: 46.0/255.0, blue: 73.0/255.0, alpha: 0.1) //UIColor(netHex:0xFFFF434)
        selectedBackgroundView = myCustomSelectionColorView



    }


    // updateUI func.
    fileprivate func updateUI() {

       // download the image
        if ( self.restData.image != nil  &&  self.restData.image != "") {
            ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlString:self.restData.image, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
                self.img.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
                self.img.image = image
            })
        } else {
            self.img.image = UIImage(named: "60x60placeholder.png")
        }


        self.lbl.text = restData.name as String



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Very Simple Not Write Much Code Only Two Lines Solve Your Problem

```
    cell.thumbnailimage.image = nil
    cell.thumbnailimage.setImageWith(imageurl!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a default value for the imageViews as "nil" in your xib-file. This will make sure not to have an image on your cell before you load in a new one.

```
func configureCell(iteminfo:ItemInfo , img1 : UIImage? , img2 : UIImage? ){

    //Set the imageViews to nil to make sure no other picture are set
    imageViewItemPic.image = nil
    imageViewCookerProfilePic.image = nil

    //Check if img1 is not nil
    if img1 != nil {
        imageViewItemPic.image = img1
    } else{
        print("hi1")
        imageViewItemPic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.imageUrl!)
    }

    //Check if img2 is not nil
    if img2 != nil {
        imageViewCookerProfilePic.image = img2
    } else{
        imageViewCookerProfilePic.setImageFromURL(url: iteminfo.cookerProfilePicUrl!)
    }

    labelItemHeading.text = iteminfo.heading
    labelItemDescription.text = iteminfo.description


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can overcome this problem with third party libraries.[Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) vs.

If you say I want to do it myself, here's how I did it. Because I needed extra security measures in image downloads (ssl pinning etc.).

Using image download in a cell actually uses the imageView reference. You need to break this reference. In my case I use the prepareForReuse function in UITableViewCell.

First I delete the UIImageView, then I create a new imageview, add it to the view and give constraint again.

The point you need to pay attention here is to create the cell as if this function does not exist when it is first created. Then let this function do its job.

```
open override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    imageViewObject?.removeFromSuperview()
    imageViewObject = createImageView()
    
    if let imageViewObject = imageViewObject {
        addSubview(imageViewObject)
        createConstraint()
        activateConstraint()
        
    }
}
```