# IOS tableview reusing old images while downloading new images issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiimage

I have read a similar post in [Reusable cell old image showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705286/reusable-cell-old-image-showing) and I am still getting the same issues. Essentially I have a TableView that downloads images from amazon s3 as you scroll down everything works good until you get to about the 12th or 13th image. What happens is that the image in the row before shows up in the new row for about 2 seconds while the new image is being downloaded . This is my code ( I'm still new at swift and learning IOS) . **The stream_image_string** as the full URL to download the images and **PicHeight** is an integer saved with the image height since every image usually has a different height .

```
var Stream_Cache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
  var stream_image_string = [String]()
    var PicHeight = [Int]()
```

This below is inside the UITableViewCell, first I check if there is a url which it will contain more than 0 characters . I then check if the image/url is saved in the Cache if not then I download it .

```
            if stream_image_string[indexPath.row].characters.count > 0 {
        if let image = Stream_Cache.object(forKey: stream_image_string[indexPath.row] as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
              DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            cell.stream_image.image = image


            })
        } else {
            if cell.stream_image != nil {
            let strCellImageURL = self.stream_image_string[indexPath.row]
            let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: strCellImageURL)!
        let request:NSURLRequest =  NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

      cell.Stream_Image_Height.constant = CGFloat(Float(cell.pic_height!))
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,    completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                if data != nil {
                cell.stream_image.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                } else {
                     cell.Stream_Image_Height.constant = 0
                    cell.stream_image.image = nil
                }


            })
        });

        task.resume()
            }
    }
    } else {

        cell.Stream_Image_Height.constant = 0
    }
```

In my UITableViewCell file I set the image to a default image in case it wasn't done loading the new image but it hasn't worked

```
class HomePageTVC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var stream_image: UIImageView!

    var pic_height: Int?




    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
      stream_image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "defaultImage")


    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're facing a pretty common cell reuse issue. When you dequeue a cell that was used before, it may already have an image installed in its image view. Set the image to nil before beginning an async download:

```
  if let imageString = stream_image_string[indexPath.row].characters,
      !imageString.isEmpty {
    if let image = Stream_Cache.object(forKey: imageString) as? UIImage {
      cell.stream_image.image = image
    } else {
      //Clear out any old image left in the recycled image view.
      cell.stream_image.image = nil
      //Your code to download the image goes here
    }
  }
```

Note that there's no need to wrap the `cell.stream_image.image = image` code in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()`. That code will be run on the main thread.

You **do**, however, need the second `DispatchQueue.main.async()` wrapper around the code inside the dataTask's completionHandler, since `URLSession`'s completion handers are called on a background queue by default.