# Reusable cell or wrong asynchronous image download from JSON data in TableView

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have an application which downloads JSON data from API and sets it in tableview cells. At some point by scrolling up/down in random cell image may change itself for several times before it has a right image in it. No problems for text data whatsoever. At first i thought the problem is reusability of cell, so i need to destroy data before i actually set new image. So i added this method of TableViewCell to cellForRowAt path to destroy data before setting a cell:

```
func destroyCellData() {

    self.newsImageView.image = nil
    self.newsTitleLabel.text = nil
    self.tagLabel.text = nil
}
```

then the actual method for setting a cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newscell") as? NewsTableViewCell else {

        print("No such cell")
        exit(14)
    }

    cell.loadingImageIndicator.startAnimating()

    let data = dataManager.getData()

    let dataToInsert = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.destroyCellData()
    cell.setDataToCell(with: dataToInsert)

    return cell
}
```

And method setDataToCell is :

```
func setDataToCell(newsObject: jsonNews) {

        self.newsTitleLabel.text = newsObject.title
        self.tagLabel.text = newsObject.tag

        let url = newsObject.imageURL
        self.newsImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "ViewPlaceholder"), indicator: loadingImageIndicator)

}
```

And finally i load asynchronously image inside cell:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

func loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(_ URLString: String, placeholder: UIImage?, indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView? = nil) {

    self.image = nil

    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: NSString(string: URLString)) {

        self.image = cachedImage
        indicator?.stopAnimating()
        return

    }

    guard let encodedString = URLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {

        print("Error Loading URL")
        return
    }

    if let url = URL(string: encodedString) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("ERROR LOADING IMAGES FROM URL: \(String(describing: error))")

                OperationManager.UI {

                    self.image = placeholder
                    indicator?.stopAnimating()
                }

                return
            }

                if let data = data {

                    if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {

                            print(URLString)
                            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: NSString(string: URLString))

                        OperationManager.UI {

                            self.image = downloadedImage
                            indicator?.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

}

so i have the question is - does the problem lie in the method in which i download and set an image or is the problem in reusability of a cell? and if that is possible give me a hint of a more appropriate way to set an image to cell. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the correct images being replaced with incorrect images?

Comment: Check out extension in this link: https://github.com/antonio081014/TwitterPractice/blob/master/TwitterPractice/Helper/Extensions.swift
Create a subclass with a string variable storing correct url string, then when image data received, check if the right image received.

Comment: @ColdLogic yes , but it appears very occasionally and eventually they are replaced with correct when scrolling the tableview

Comment: @IhorDemchenko so if you scroll just 1 cell into view, it can be the wrong one, and eventually updates to the correct one?\

Comment: You need to find a way to cancel the image download and add it to destroyCellData. Most likely the reason is because as you scroll fast there are multiple images being loaded in the same image view.

Comment: @DevPerfecular thank you so much. it was definitely  a solution, a code example is pretty nice. All i lack was a Field for each image to check if thats an appropriate url for image

Comment: [My answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77981454/4571664) You can try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having your code, I suspect your problem is probably with both the reusable cells and async image downloading. In that, when you reload the cell, it kicks off a data task to download an image, and if a second task is started to download a different image, nothing happens to the first.

For example, lets say your first image is 100MB, and the second image for the reusabel cell will be 1KB. Hopefully 1KB downloads faster. Here is the flow

1. Load cell with `image1`
2. Start download of `image1`
3. Load cell with `image2`
4. Start download of `image2`
5. Complete download of `image2`
6. Set cell image to `image2`
7. Complete download of `image1`
8. Set cell image to `image1`

Since the data task of downloading image1 completed after image2 had already been set, cell will get the update to show image1 after it is displaying image2, and thus show the wrong image.

To solve your problem, you need someway to cancel the first operation, or rather, not update the image view if its no longer displaying that data. There are many ways to do this. One solution is creating a property of the image url on your cell, and when the download completes, confirm its the correct url, and if it is, update the image view.

```
func setDataToCell(newsObject: jsonNews) {
    // Your other code
    self.imageURL = newsObject.imageURL
}

// loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString
if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {

    print(URLString)
    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: NSString(string: URLString))

    OperationManager.UI {
        if url.absoluteString == self.imageURL {
            self.image = downloadedImage
            indicator?.stopAnimating()
        } 
    }
}
```

**NOTE: Didn't test any of this code, and wrote it straight from my brain. It could have errors.**

With all that said, I recommend using a third party image caching system like [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) or one of the other ones that people have commented on.

Comment: Thank you so much ! That was definitely a problem so i solved it with a customUIImageView with urlString property. Images load slower but no collisions in tableViewCells. And I was not using Alamofire for purpose - to figure out how exactly that thing works and to build my own templates for further work and better understanding of an architecture of such frameworks

Answer (score -2):

you can use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher for async image load. This takes care of caching and rendering correct images for corresponding index

Comment: The same problem as in other fake solutions - your link is about async image loading and caching but doesn't support images in cells - you need to add your own code for them